# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess while sharing session between Rails 2 and Rails 4 Applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am getting the following issue while trying to share session between Rails 2 and Rails 4 Applications.

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load_missing_constant'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `rake_original_const_missing'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2465:in `const_missing'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:31:in `load'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:31:in `verify'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:171:in `unmarshal'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:159:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:257:in `stale_session_check!'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:156:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
    /home/dinesh/tracoffshore/offshore/lib/rails_4_session_flash_backport/rails2/session_with_indifferent_access.rb:43:in `load_session'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:132:in `send'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:132:in `load!'
    /home/dinesh/tracoffshore/offshore/lib/rails_4_session_flash_backport/rails2/session_with_indifferent_access.rb:14:in `[]'
    /home/dinesh/tracoffshore/offshore/vendor/plugins/authlogic-connect/lib/authlogic_connect/callback_filter.rb:14:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:98:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:48:in `service'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
    /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    script/server:4:in `require'
    script/server:4
```

I am taking help from the following 3 links.

https://www.theguild.nl/share-sessions-between-rails-2-and-rails-3-applications

https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails/3-steps-to-share-a-session-between-rails-3-and-rails-4-applications-9618766e6c2a#.1q15dg9a4.

http://webuild.envato.com/blog/upgrading-ruby-on-rails-at-production-scale/

Still not able to add ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess class to my rails 2 app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest against taking this approach as it's likely to lead to a ton of headaches like the above.

`ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` is not available in Rails versions prior to 3. You can likely shoehorn HashWithIndifferentAccess into Rails 2, but honestly I think it would be much more worthwhile to upgrade the legacy system.

It's also rather difficult to give much insight without the code that produced the error.